# C# Using Socket.Receive(bytes) takes about 3 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-6.0

I am using .NET 6.0 and recently using `int numBytes = client.Receive(bytes);` has been taking around about 3 minutes.
The Socket variable is called `client`.
This issue was not occuring 3 days ago.

The full code that I am using is:

```
string data = "";
byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

client = httpServer.Accept();
// Read inbound connection data
while (true)
{
    int numBytes = client.Receive(bytes); // Taking about 3 minutes here
    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, numBytes);

    if (data.IndexOf("\r\n") > -1 || data == "")
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The timing is also not always consistent. Sometimes (rarely) it can be instant and othertimes it can take 3 minutes - 1 hour.

I have attempted the following:

- Restarting my computer
- Changing networks
- Turning off the firewall
- Attempting on a different computer
- Attempting on a different computer with the firewall off
- Using a wired and wireless connection
  However none of these worked and instead resulted in the same issue.
  What I expect to happen and what used to happen is that it would continue through the code normally instead of being hung up on 1 line of code for a long time.

Comment: Why this should be a problem? - You use blocking API, no data received for underlying socket structure - thread is blocked then. You can use async version also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `client.Poll()` method to check if data is available to be read from the socket before calling `client.Receive()`.

If `client.Poll()` returns false, it means that there is no data available to be read and you can handle that situation accordingly.